# Altered my database structure in development, so tried to reset Heroku deployed database. Erased it but now I can't migrate my db over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

so my app was working fine. I created a new model and some associaitons, rendering all the old seed data in my heroku app useless. so I tried to reset it and populate it again. but I can't even migrate my db to heroku with the `heroku rake db:migrate` command. I'm using SQLite, but it seems my error is related to Postgres. I don't know what that means, if anything

Here is the error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  column "to" cannot be cast to type "pg_catalog.int4"
: ALTER TABLE "emails" ALTER COLUMN "to" TYPE integer

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

My migration:

```
class ChangeDataTypeForEmailUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
      change_column :emails, :to, :integer
      change_column :emails, :from, :integer
  end

  def self.down
      change_column :to, :string
      change_column :from, :string
  end
end
```

What is the problem? My deployed app was working fine. I added a new model and figured I should reset the deployed database. So I ran `heroku pg:reset` then pushed my code to heroku. then tried to migrate the db, but it doesn't work! What have I done? I have been trying to figure this out for the last 4 hours. I can't think straight anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the content of your database.yml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per heroku docs [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#common_issues_migrating_to_postgresql)

**Cause:** PostgreSQL doesn’t know how to cast all the rows in that table to the specified type. Most likely it means you have an integer or a string in that column.

**Solution:** Inspect your records and make sure they can be converted to the new type. Sometimes it’s easier to just avoid using change_column, **renaming/creating a new column instead.**

I also was in this position before and i did not find a solution so i had to create a new column, postgresql seems to be sensitive when i comes to this issues. Hope it helps

Answer (score 8):

Further to Hishalv's answer. If you can't use "change_column" then you can go the roundabout way:

```
 def self.up
   rename_column :emails, :to, :old_to
   add_column :emails, :to, :integer
   Email.reset_column_information
   Email.all.each {|e| e.update_attribute(:to, e.old_to.to_i) }
   remove_column :emails, :old_to
 end
```

It's roundabout, and the `Email.all.each` might be slow - but it'll work and correctly cast for you.

If you're only going to use it on prod, then you might be able to replace the ruby-updates with a SQL UPDATE command that does the same thing in-database using a POSTGRES-specific cast method.

Comment: @TarynEast I tried your solution and it worked. Thanks! However Email.each should be Email.all.each. Could you fix it? I could not edit because I had to change 6 characters at least.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for spotting that one.